# Why is the flatmap-operator not working as I understood it?

Tags: express, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, flatmap

`fetch(url)` returns a promise, which I'm converting to observable using **flatmap**. Why is this not working?

```
Rx.Observable
    .from(imgSrc)
    .map(url => fetch(url))
    .flatmap( res => R.Observable.fromPromise(res))
    .subscribe(
        function(res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    },
                    function(err){
                        console.log("Errorororrororororor:"+JSON.stringify(err));
                        response.status(500).send(
                                        {
                                            "error":err
                                        });
                    },
                    function(){
                        console.log("completed promise!!")
                        response.status(200).send(
                                        {"data": [{
                                               "id": "testing id",
                                               "url": "https://test.com/1.jpg"
                                           }]
                                        });
                    }
    );
```

Comment: How it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you have `R.Observable.fromPromise` with just `R` at the beginning instead of `Rx`?

Comment: @martin.. Ok got it.. you are right..I got confused with the input to flatmap callback.. will delete this answer..I guess OP`s problem is a typo.

Comment: Also the operation is `flatMap` not `flatmap`

Comment: Thank you very much. I hate JS just because of this typos R and flatmap... grr...........